# XSD identifier pattern

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to create an identifier of the form `1120XXXTP`, where `XXX` is a code and `TP` is type: `lc, lb, pr or ex`

This is what i have so far

```
<xs:simpleType name="complex" >
 <xs:union>
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
      <xs:pattern value="[1][1][2][0][0-9]{3}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="lc" />
      <xs:enumeration value="lb" />
      <xs:enumeration value="pr" />
      <xs:enumeration value="ex" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:union>
```

This is an example in the XML of what the identifier should look like

```
<Classes>
    <CoursePartReference code="1120002lc">
```

I'm not able to set the pattern correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match your identifier with a single regex pattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="1120\d{3}(lc|lb|pr|ex)" />
```

Altogether, then this XML,

```
<CoursePartReference code="1120002lc">
```

will be valid against this XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="CoursePartReference">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="code">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="1120\d{3}(lc|lb|pr|ex)" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```